# How can I attach broken piece of shott ceran induction cooktop?

Tags: appliances

A 1" x 2" piece of my Schott Ceran induction cooktop broke off.  I'd like to "glue" it back on.  It doesn't interfere with any of the "burners".  May I do this and if so, what glue is the best to use?

Comment: So you're trying to make this cooktop waterproof again?

Comment: the corner broke off and I'd like to glue it back on.  I suppose it would be good to make a waterproof seal along the crack line.